# Get StdOut of a executable called by psexec.exe with powershell

Tags: powershell, stdout, psexec

I try to get the StdOut Error message from vmrun.exe by calling it via psexec.exe. Unfortunately, it is not available and there is no proper error description. By calling the vmrun.exe directly this information is available. Is there a way to bypass the information to the psexec?

```
function Invoke-Process {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param
        (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$FilePath,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ArgumentList,

        [ValidateSet("Full","StdOut","StdErr","ExitCode","None")]
        [string]$DisplayLevel
        )

    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

    try {
        $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        $pinfo.FileName = $FilePath
        $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
        $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true      

        $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
        $pinfo.WindowStyle = 'Hidden'
        $pinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
        $pinfo.Arguments = $ArgumentList
        $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
        $p.Start() | Out-Null
        $p.WaitForExit()
        $result = [pscustomobject]@{
        Title = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand).Name
        Command = $FilePath
        Arguments = $ArgumentList
        StdOut = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        StdErr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
        ExitCode = $p.ExitCode
        }
        

        if (-not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($DisplayLevel))) {
            switch($DisplayLevel) {
                "Full" { return $result; break }
                "StdOut" { return $result.StdOut; break }
                "StdErr" { return $result.StdErr; break }
                "ExitCode" { return $result.ExitCode; break }
                }
            }
        }
    catch {
        
        }
}

write-host "******************************Call vmrun directly******************************"
Invoke-Process -FilePath  "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe" -ArgumentList "stop E:\VMs\VM1\vm1.vmx" -DisplayLevel Full
write-host "******************************Call vmrun from psexec******************************"
Invoke-Process -FilePath  "C:\Windows\System32\PsExec64.exe" -ArgumentList """C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe"" stop E:\VMs\VM1\vm1.vmx" -DisplayLevel Full
```

[This is how the output looks like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl9sh.png)

Comment: Try putting `\. ` before the file path.

Comment: Sorry Jesse, I didn't get you. Where should I put the "\."?

Comment: In the arguments of psexec, before the file path.

Comment: Invoke-Process  -FilePath  "C:\Windows\System32\PsExec64.exe" -ArgumentList "\. ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe"" stop E:\VMs\VM1\vm1.vmx" -DisplayLevel Full

Comment: Output is:             PsExec could not start \.:
            
ExitCode  : 5